# Uploading images in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have being using django for sometime but recently noticed this. Before now I thought images in django, by default, gets uploaded in the
path specified in `STATIC_URL` but I just saw that the bahaviour is diffrent in my app. I have this set up in settings.py:

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Categories.choices, default=Categories.medications)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    image = ResizedImageField(upload_to='images/blog/', null=True, blank=True)
    introduction = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()

settings.py

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static',),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/build/static'),
    ]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

The static, staticfiles, and media are within the root directory. In my django app, if media directory isn't present the
images get uploaded in `static` directory. However, when both static and media directorie are present preference is given to the media
directory (the images get uploaded in media directory). Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`STATIC_ROOT` was used to store all kinds of files like JavaScript, CSS and media files. Bot now the `MEDIA_ROOT` is used explicit for images and other media. That's where all you medias should go, you can also create additional directories in `MEDIA_ROOT` ex. for each model you have.
More about `MEDIA_ROOT` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_ROOT)